# Chaincode registration failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I have tried to instantiate nodejs chaincode on multiple host environment and resulted in chaincode registration error. Golang smart contract worked perfectly in multiple host env.

**Error** :  `could not assemble transaction. err propseal response was not succesful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exiter with 127`

**Peer log:**

```
2019-11-05 06:03:09.941 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 04c [mychannel][6e8f647c] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: container exited with 127
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:63
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
chaincode registration failed
```

Anything need to be changed in environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the CC_SRC_PATH github/chaincode/.

Answer (score 0):

can you just try removing all the docker containers and install, instantiate chaincode once again.

Comment: tried removing all the containers and installed the chaincode. Installation was successful all the times but error occurs while instantiating